# How to make sure a clocked operation happens just once in Vhdl

Tags: vhdl, clock, control, ram

title may be a bit confusing but what I try to do is to take data from ram/modify it and put that data back to the ram. I want all of this to happen just for the operation(Brightness/Contrast) time when I enable the system instead of happening over and over to the point where data becomes deformed. Here is the code. I want write_enable(which enables writing to ram) to stay at 1 just for the operation(in a window which I call cursor) time then go back to 0 even if enable is 1. This is some image processing and I change brightness and contrast of the image in a window I call cursor. This change must happen for all pixels inside cursor just once. I tried many things(complex control mechanism) but failed due to vivado's unused element removal issue.I am totally out of idea on how to do that. How can I construct such a control mechanism??? I put commends(from here/to here) to show where this problem takes place.

```
rst is input
clk and clk2 are different clock signals
done is signal
data_in_ram is ram input
output_of_operation is output of change of Brightness or contrast operation
data_rom is output of rom
PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT is length of my square picture (250*250)
pos_x and pos_y are signals that denote pixel coordinates
cursor_pos_x and cursor_pos_y are upper-left coordinate of the window or cursor
length is length of the square window or cursor
clk is 25Mhz
clk2 is 50Mhz. this is chosen 50 due to ram's read latency(2 clock cycle)
```

The ram and rom below are constructed using block memory generator.

```
Reading_Writing_Resetting_Ram: process(clk2,clk,rst) is
begin

    if rst = '1' then    
      done <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then    
        if done = '0' then
            if address_rom < conv_std_logic_vector((PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16) then
                write_enable <= '1';
                data_in_ram <= data_rom;
                address_ram <= address_rom;
                address_rom <= address_rom + 1;
            else
                address_rom <= (others => '0');
                write_enable <= '0';
                done <= '1';
            end if;
            -------------------------------------part above is for resetting ram
        else --if done = '1' --From here    
            if ( pos_x >= cursor_pos_x ) and (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( pos_y >= cursor_pos_y) and (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length) then --if within cursor

                address_ram <=(conv_std_logic_vector((pos_x + pos_y*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16));
                data_in_ram <= output_of_operation;   

                if enable = '1' then    
                    write_enable <= '1';
                else    
                    write_enable <= '0';    
                end if; -- enable    
            else --if out of cursor -- to here
                -------------------------- part below is for reading from ram
                write_enable <= '0';

                if (pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_x >= 0) and (pos_y >= 0) then -- if within picture

                    address_ram <=(conv_std_logic_vector((pos_x + pos_y*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT),16));

                end if; 
            end if; 
        end if; 
    end if;    
end process;
```

This code below is used for second condition for write_enable but vivado removes this components.

```
Adjusting_enable2: process(rst,clk,cursor_pos_x,cursor_pos_y,enable,cursor_mode,current_cursor_mode,c_cursor_pos_x,c_cursor_pos_y) is
begin
if (rst = '1') or (cursor_mode /= current_cursor_mode) or (c_cursor_pos_x /= cursor_pos_x) or (c_cursor_pos_y /= cursor_pos_y)  then

enable2 <= '1';
c_cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x;
c_cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y;
counter_for_enable2 <= 0;

elsif rising_edge(clk) then

if enable ='1' then

if counter_for_enable2 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT*PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT then

counter_for_enable2 <= counter_for_enable2 + 1;

else

enable2 <= '0';

end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your code was indented properly

Comment: Please edit your post and indent your VHDL properly (recommend 2 spaces, no tabs), it's too awkward to follow. Also, break up your single big paragraph above it into distinct sections. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Downvoting til then.

Comment: I do not know much about indenting but I tried my best.

Comment: Also cross posting is frowned upon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254445/issue-about-making-sure-that-the-operation-takes-place-once-in-vhdl. (Yes, some of us keep track of both!)

Comment: You can prevent removal of unused elements by using "attribute keep : string;"  
"attribute keep of xxx : signal is "true";".  See page 58.  https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/sw_manuals/xilinx2022_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Comment: Where is "enable2 " used?   If its not used then Vivado will remove the second block by default.

Comment: How do pos_x and pos_y get updated.  The way your first block is set up, your operation will happen continuously as long as your x/y are within the window.  That's probably find if pos_x and pos_y are only on each pixel for 1 clock cycles (like updated by a counter, etc), but might have problems if they come from say a user controlled cursor.

Comment: @onurkirmizi Your sensitivity lists are completely bogus, if you want a synthesizable and maintainable code. **Reading_Writing_Resetting_Ram**: 1. Sensitize only on the clock and ONE clock only, and maybe on an async reset. 2. If you are using FPGA, why are you using an async reset? Rewrite to use a sync reset if possible. **Adjusting_enable2**: 1. only sensitize on clock reset, 2. create a dedicated async reset signal or better, use a dedicated sync reset. Also: see my comment here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454454/vhdl-process-sensitivity-list/697413#697413

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't(?)... I think you should draw your design before you type, you will get much more out of the experience and suffer less issues like you have been posting... nonetheless, you stated:

> I want write_enable(which enables writing to ram) to stay at 1 just for the operation(in a window which I call cursor) time then go back to 0 even if enable is 1

Not sure if it solves your overall issue, but based on this sentence, it translates to AND'ing cursor and enable.

combinatorial: `write_enable = cursor and enable;`

inside a clocked process: `write_enable <= cursor and enable;`

Comment: but cursor is of integer type

Comment: And, cursor is valid for certain values?  Create an enable signal via comparisons similar to what you have done for your RGB values.  e.g. `if (cursor > <somevalue>) and (cursor < <somevalue>) then cursor_enable <= '1'; else cursor_enable <= '0';..`  I haven't studied all the details of your circuit, and there is probably a better way to accomplish the same thing, but as we take this path, this should satisfy your statement, unless I am missing some tertiary condition/item(?)

Comment: I put a code above which I tried but got removal error

Comment: I thought we covered that in an earlier post. Those signals are not used anywhere in the code you have posted, anyway, so, synthesizer removes them.  If I understand this correctly, I am assuming enable2 is your pulse for your "window valid" time(?)  if so, use the enable2 AND'ed with the other enable, and  you should get the behavior you described.  And, because you use it, your synthesizer wont remove it.

Comment: BTW, why aren't you simulating this first?  it seems you are in a mode we call "burn and churn" which is type -> syn -> load in HW -> cross fingers and hope.  You should, instead, draw -> type -> simulate, and **then** syn (and, hope probably too).  Trust me on this.

Comment: Although I do that. Vivado will remove other things related to enable2 and enable2 is like what you say(valid time).

Comment: **IF** the other "things" contribute to enable2, and enable 2 is used, and the resulting signals related to enable2 usage are used, and so on...  synthesizer will not remove them, except, possibly through optimization because you wrote code that wasn't efficient (which happens to seasoned folks too, sometimes because of convenience of RTL code, blah-blah..) and it found another way to implement the same thing and maintain the same functionality.  Your simulation, should you choose to use it, will confirm this functionality